# Связь One-to-Many с отличающимся именем поля и таблицы

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Хочу создать связь: пост может иметь одного автора, у которого может быть множество постов.

```
builder.HasOne(p => p.Author)
    .WithMany(u => u.Posts)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.AuthorId);
```

Пост это обычный класс `Post`, а автор это класс унаследованный от `IdentityUser` - `ApplicationUser`.

Нужно ли как-то дополнять команду выше, если имя таблицы будет `Users` (а то и `ASP.NetUsers`, если я не уберу префиксы), а не `Author` или EntityFramework сам сориентируется, глядя на типы полей?

Comment: Эээ, ну вы уже попробовали? И что-то не получилось?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, пока ещё нет. Я ещё описываю логику EF, а до проверки дело дойдёт, когда перейду к написанию непосредственно ASP.Net Core приложения. Просто хотелось заранее написать правильно

Comment: Пока у вас проблемы нет. Приходите, когда проблема будет :)